# Eclipse doesn't clean itself

Tags: android, eclipse

When I change something (id values mainly) in my Android XML files I need to manually clean the project. Otherwise I will get errors in code when I try to access those elements with the id I just created.

Today I was wondering why my menu buttons had their actions reversed. I had changed the order of my menu elements. They showed correctly, but the ids were flipped. I cleaned the project and re-uploaded it to my phone and it started working.

What is wrong with Eclipse?

Comment: For newly created Id to appear in code select build automatically from the project tab. As for the weird behavior of buttons you will have to clean the project because that creates the id for all the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]In Eclipse you can see in menu bar

> project----->Build Automatically enable it.....

Comment: You mean `Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Build automatically`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the option Project -> Build automatically, if you have it checked whenever you make a change in any xml file, this will change in R.java file.